# remove a class from parent when a class is added to the child

Tags: jquery

An error class is added to the input field when an incorrect password is entered. When a correct password is entered, a class called "Valid" is added to the li containing the password input tag. How do I remove the valid class on li when error class appears on the input field.

```
<li class="Valid">
        <input type="password" class="error" placeholder="Password" id="aim_Password" name="password"></input>
        </li>
```

Note: I'm using jquery validation plugin to add the error class to the input field and looking for a cross browser solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this!

You can use the keyPress() event too to detect if the classes of the input have been modified while you were typing:

```
$('#aim_Password').bind('keyPress',function(){
     var has_error_class = $(this).hasClass('error');
     if(has_error_class){
             $(this).parent().removeClass('Valid');
     }        
});
```